# How to write this in an elegant way (cell arrays and structs in MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, coding-style, struct, plot, cell-array

I would like to **plot connected points** in MATLAB.

My connected points come from connecting objects of *"stats"*, where each *"stat"* comes from a **BW regionprops** struct.

The code I have written works, but it suffers from a lot of *"ugliness"*, which I couldnt fix even after trying various ways.

```
function plot_line( line )

a = cell2mat(line);
b = {a.Centroid};

matx = {};
maty = {};

for i = 1:size(b,2)
    matx{end+1} = b{i}(1);
    maty{end+1} = b{i}(2);
end

plot ( cell2mat(matx), cell2mat(maty) );

end
```

Can you help me make this code nicer? It's not critical, as my code works fine and as the lines are short (<100 points) the performance is not an issue.

It is just that it would be really nice to know how this tiny function **should be written** in the proper way, without for loops and 3 calls of cell2mat.

In my example:

- line is a `<1xn cell>`,
- `line{1}` has a property `'Centroid'` and
- `line{i}.Centroid(1)` are the x coordinates and
- `line{i}.Centroid(2)` are the y coordinates.

Actually, all I need is plotting `line{i}.Centroid(1)`, `line{i}.Centroid(2)` for `i = 1:size(line,2)`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
line = repmat({struct('Centroid',[1 2])},1,5);   %# similar to the data you have

%# extract x/y coordinates
x = cellfun(@(s)s.Centroid(1),line)
y = cellfun(@(s)s.Centroid(2),line)

%# plot
plot(x,y)
```

You could also do it as:

```
xy = cell2mat(cellfun(@(s)s.Centroid, line, 'UniformOutput',false)');
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a cell array `b`, you can create a numerical array directly, by catenating using [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html):

```
tmp = cat(1,line{:});

coordinates = cat(1,tmp.Centroid);

plot(coordinates(:,1),coordinates(:,2))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep it really short (i.e. even shorter than [@Amro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073025/how-to-write-this-in-an-elegant-way-cell-arrays-and-structs-in-matlab/8073919#8073919) you can use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) like this in order get a one-liner:

```
plot(cellfun(@(x)x.Centroid(1),line),cellfun(@(x)x.Centroid(2),line))
```